# 12 V, 6 A battery charger with nichrome flat wire

Tags: power-supply, batteries, charger, heat

Is it possible to use a 12 V, 6 A car battery charger with nichrome or copper flat wire to cut 8 mm synthetic rope? If so, what spec (length, width, thickness, type) of nichrome flat wire could I use for this?

Comment: It depends on the charger. If it is a smart chager, it might detect that there is no battery.

Comment: Why flat wire ?

Comment: For a dumb charger, sure. How much current can it supply?

Comment: Thanks, it is actually a 12v 6 amp charger as in pic attached. I used it keep a boat battery charged up but would like to reuse it as a heat cutter for boat rope. I also thought a flat wire would be best suited for cutting rope. I will measure output with a multimeter and then confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At 12 V and 6 A, you need 2 ohm or higher. At 2 ohm, you are however putting 72 W into your wire, which is a lot so you may melt it if it's too short. Nichrome is 112 μΩcm. You need to calculate your diameter and length from that to and up with 2 ohm or higher and not melt it.

Have a look here: [Can I using nichrome wire to light a candle electronicaly?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/20542/can-i-using-nichrome-wire-to-light-a-candle-electronicaly)